# Css and bootstrap not working in chrome but does in live server

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Using Vscode to create a webpage, it displays all my css and bootstrap sass exactly how I programmed but when I open it normally as a webpage without using Vscode live server it doesn't show the css and some bootstrap sass

Comment: This question is too vague to get answers. If you add more information, what have you tried, errors and maybe some screenshots, you are more likely to get some responses.

Comment: What do you mean by "open it normally as a webpage"? Opening by double-clicking the html file? Or opening from a different web server?

Answer (score 0):

Check the paths for your dependencies, probably css can not be loaded because of absolute/relative paths

Answer (score 0):

Please check the path of your css and bootstrap dependency.